# Algorithm for positioning rectangles of various size into a larger rectangle

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I am working on tool for merging smaller textures into one larger for use on Android app.

I have $n$ rectangles of given size $(w_k, h_k)$, where $k=1,\ldots,n$ and I need to position them within master rectangle of size $2^l \times 2^m$, where $l, m \leq 9$ so none overlapping occur and $2^l \times 2^m$ has minimal possible value. The result should be $(x_k, y_k)$, a position of each of the $n$ base rectangles or information that such positioning is impossible.

Comment: Minus the specific dimensions you list, your problem is known as "bin packing" in the literature.  And the literature is vast.  See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

I guess [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx)
 should be exactly what you need. Basically it is an implementation of the approach presented in [this](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICAPS/2003/ICAPS03-029.pdf) paper by Richard E. Korf.
To quote the introduction:

> Given a set of rectangles with fixed orientations, we want to
>   find an enclosing rectangle of minimum area that contains
>   them all with no overlap. Many simple scheduling tasks can
>   be modelled by this NP-complete problem. We use an anytime
>   branch-and-bound algorithm to solve the problem optimally.

Answer (score 1):

We seem to have an number (I will use $k$) of identical $w \times h$ rectangles to fit inside a larger $2^n \times 2^m$ rectangles, and with a restrictions on $n$ and $m$.

For given $2^n$, we can fit $\lfloor 2^n / w \rfloor$ rectangles horizontally provided $w \le 2^n$.  So we need at least $ \lceil k / \lfloor 2^n / w \rfloor \rceil$ rows of rectangles and so a vertical height of at least $ h \lceil k / \lfloor 2^n / w \rfloor \rceil$; if this is less than or equal to $2^m$ then there is a solution and the minimal value of $m$ is  $ \lceil \log_2 \left( h \lceil k / \lfloor 2^n / w \rfloor \rceil \right) \rceil$.  The area of the master rectangle is then $2^{n+ \lceil \log_2 \left( h \lceil k / \lfloor 2^n / w \rfloor \rceil \right) \rceil}$. It is probably worth testing this for the ten(?) possible values of $n$ to see which produces the minimal master rectangle.

As for the coordinates (assuming these are one of the corners and $(0,0)$ is a possibility), this will be a matter of style.  One way would be to use $(iw,jh)$ for nonengative integers $i$ and $j$ so long as $(i+1)w -1 \le 2^n$ and  $(j+1)h -1 \le 2^m$.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - there are not identical. Each of them have wn x kn size where n = 1, 2, ..., k